# Make foo(derived_object) call foo(Base const&) instead of template function?

Tags: c++, overload-resolution

Given this code:

```
template< class C >
void foo( C const& o ) { o.nosuch(); }

struct Base {};
void foo( Base const& ) {}

struct Derived: Base {};

auto main() -> int
{
    Derived d;
    foo( d );       // !Invokes template.
}
```

… I want the call to invoke the overload defined for `Base`, without having to define an overload or template specialization for `Derived`.

The goal is to be able to apply `foo` to all kinds of objects, not just `Base` (and `Derived`) objects, with a generic implementation for most kinds of objects.

It would also be nice if an answer explained exactly how overload resolution works in this case, versus how it works with a `Derived` overload defined.

---

In the code where this problem manifested, `foo` above is a function template `n_items` defined as follows:

```
template< class Type >
auto n_items( Type const& o )
    -> size_t
{ return o.size(); }

template< size_t n >
auto n_items( std::bitset<n> const& o )
    -> size_t
{ return o.count(); }       // Corresponds to std::set<int>::size()

template< class Type, size_t n >
constexpr
auto n_items( Raw_array_of_<n, Type> const& a )
    -> size_t
{ return static_size( a ); }
```

And the intent is that this should be a catch-all for types that don't define their own `n_items` overloads.

And for a base and derived class, it should be enough that the base class defines a custom `n_items`; it would be very redundant to have to define it for every derived class.

Comment: what are your constraints? Is modifying the template acceptable? Is modifying the `Base` function acceptable, is it preferable? Is your template really a "catch everything except everything derived from `Base`? Wish you would clarify some more.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Well, a bit more concrete, the goal is to be able to write `n_items( o )` for all kinds of object `o`, including `std::vector` (where it invokes `size` member), `std::bitset` (where it invokes `count`, I think it was), raw arrays, and my own string classes, where one is derived from a more general one. The `n_items` template is specialized for bitset and raw array, and has a generic implementation as a catch-all for types that don't define their own overloads.

Comment: If you have a specific return type that does not depend on the argument type, you can also create a struct `template<typename R, typename F> struct UserConv { R r; template<typename U> UserConv(U &&u):r(F::call(u)) { } };` which allows you to say `struct SizeCall { template<typename T> static size_t call(const T& t) { return t.size(); } };` and use `size_t foo(UserConv<size_t, SizeCall> uc) { return uc.r; }`. This  overload has user-defined conversion cost and is always second-choice against derived-to-base conversion. All it needs is some SFINAE protection against `size()` not being found.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb; :) That's ingenious. Heh.

Comment: What is `In_ref_<T>`?

Comment: @Barry: As you can guess, both from the name and from the correspondence with the simplified example, it's a reference in-argument. But you don't need to look at that original code. It was provided because more context was asked for.

Comment: This question is under discussion on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319747/3933332).

Comment: Oh, OK, so you are the one that defines the catch all functions and you want to let the user define their specialized functions for a class or a hierarchy of classes, without the need of deal with SFINAE or traits, right?

Comment: @skypjack; Yes, exactly. I'm sorry that my explanations of the problem are a bit lacking. Hm.

Comment: No, it's me, I'm not a native speaker and usually I get half of the sentences!! :-) ... Let me have another try with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

#### How overload resolution works

First we do name lookup and template type deduction. For `foo(d)`, this gives us two options:

1. `foo(Derived const&)`, with `[C = Derived]`
2. `foo(Base const&)`

These are our viable candidates.

Then we determine which one of the overloads is the best viable candidate. This is done first by looking at conversion sequences. In this case, (1) is an Exact Match whereas (2) involves a derived-to-base conversion which has Conversion rank (see [this table](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#tab:over.conversions)). Since that ranks worse, candidate (1) is preferred and is thus deemed the best viable candidate.

#### How to do what you really want

The simplest way is to simply add a third overload for `Derived`:

3. `foo(Derived const&)`

Here, both (1) and (3) would be equivalent in terms of conversion sequence. But functions that aren't templates are preferred to functions that are templates (think of it as picking the most specific option), so (3) would be selected.

But you don't want to do that. So the options are either: make (1) not work for `Derived` or make (2) work for `Derived` too in a way that's preferred.

#### Disable the general template

We can use SFINAE to simply exclude anything derived from `Base`:

```
template <class T, class = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_convertible<T*, Base*>::value>
void foo(T const& ); // new (1)

void foo(Base const& ); // same (2)
```

Now, `(1)` is no longer a viable candidate for the match, so (2) is trivally preferred.

#### Redo the overloads so that the Base is preferred

Taking a tip out of [Xeo's book](https://rmf.io/cxx11/overload-ranking/), we can restructure the overloads thusly:

```
template <int I> struct choice : choice<I + 1> { };
template <> struct choice<10> { };
struct otherwise { otherwise(...) {} };

template <class T> void foo(T const& val) { foo_impl(val, choice<0>{}); }
```

And now we can prefer those types derived from `Base`:

```
template <class T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<T*, Base*>::value>>
void foo_impl(T const& val, choice<0> ); // new (2)

template <class T>
void foo_impl(T const& val, otherwise ); // new (1)
```

This changes the mechanics of how overload resolution works and is worth going through into the separate cases.

Calling `foo(d)` means we're calling `foo_impl(d, choice<0> )` and gives us two viable candidates:

1. `foo_impl(Derived const&, choice<0> )`, with `[T = Derived]`
2. `foo_impl(Derived const&, otherwise )`, with `[T = Derived]`

Here, the first argument is identical, but for the second argument, the first overload is an Exact Match while the second argument requires a Conversion via a variadic argument. `otherwise` will always be the word choice as a result, so the first overload is preferred. Exactly what we want.

Calling `foo(not_a_base)`, on the other hand, would only give us *one* viable candidate:

1. `foo_impl(NotABase const&, otherwise )`, with `[T = NotABase]`

The other one was removed due to the deduction failure. So this is trivially the best viable candidate, and again we get exactly what we want.

---

For your specific question, I'd write something like:

```
template <class T>
size_t n_items(T const& cont) { return n_items(cont, choice<0>{}); }
```

with:

```
// has count?
template <class T>
auto n_items(T const& cont, choice<0> ) -> decltype(cont.count()) {
    return cont.count();
}

// else, has size?
template <class T>
auto n_items(T const& cont, choice<1> ) -> decltype(cont.size()) {
    return cont.size();
}

// else, use static_size
template <class T>
size_t n_items(T const& cont, otherwise )
    return static_size(cont);
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of deferring to an implementation function that has a overload-resolution-directing argument. I'm sure this can be simplified much? Thanks. :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf What?

Comment: I meant, the levels-of-preference machinery `choice<n>` isn't really needed here.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf You never know. IT's just the most general solution. Added an example for your use-case.

Comment: Oh thanks. I didn't think of that! That's good, it would deal with `std::bitset` automatically if `count` is given most preferred level, `choice<0>`. Or I believe so by looking at it. As mentioned I'm not smart today, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Put all the non-template functions in some namespace:

```
namespace Foo {
    void foo( Base const& ) {}
}
```

Then define the function template thusly:

```
template <typename C>
auto foo_aux(C const& c, int) -> decltype(Foo::foo(c)) {
    return Foo::foo(c);}
template <typename C>
void foo_aux(C const& c, ...) {
    c.nosuch();}

template <typename C>
void foo(C const& c) {foo_aux(c, 0);}
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e990e4c833851b8). This will call the general overload if and only if none of the non-template overloads match (or are ambiguous).

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but that will only work for types known at the place of definition of the template. That is, then the template only supports a limited, fixed set of types.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf So you want the template overload to be the "last" choice ever explored?

Comment: Yes. And right now I'm pretty stupid. Or I feel that way. So I just asked! :) Maybe there isn't even a solution.

Comment: Oh, mr. SFINAE to the rescue! :) Here I was thinking possibly "no way", and now there's two ways, at the least. Hm.

Comment: Why an `inline` namespace in particular?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Good point, I guess. I first thought of something more elegant that used them, but that wasn't my final approach.

Answer (score 3):

The main technical problem is that a general function template `foo` (say), instantiated for `Derived` argument, is a better match than the overload for `Base` argument.

---

### Brute force solution (redundancy).

One simple possible solution is to require overloads of all the relevant functions for every class derived from a `Base`.

However, this breaks the **DRY** rule, *Don't Repeat Yourself*.

Needless redundancy in code leads to maintenance problems.

---

### Namespace for SFINAE.

Another possible solution, [suggested by Columbo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36223904/464581), is to “put all the non-template functions in some [specific single] namespace”, which allows a general function template to use SFINAE to detect if a relevant overload exists.

This solution avoids the redundancy, and as I recall it is the kind of solution used for `boost::intrusive_ptr`, that client code must specialize the functionality in some specific namespace.

However, since it imposes a restriction on client code it feels not perfect to me.

---

### Extra argument to direct overload resolution.

A third possible solution, [suggested by Barry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36223970/464581), is to let the base class implementation have an associated overload, or just a differently named function, that has an extra argument that serves to direct the overload resolution, and that is called by by a general function template.

This is technically a solution but IMO it's not clean: the client code invocations don't match the overloads that must be provided.

And so again there is a potential maintenance problem.

---

### Invoking the function template from a simple converting overload.

[Johannes Schaub suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36223766/make-fooderived-object-call-foobase-const-instead-of-template-function?noredirect=1#comment60079494_36223766) a fourth possible solution, which allows clean, simple client code, namely to let an ordinary overload call the function template, but where that general implementation overload has a formal argument type that

1. introduces a user defined conversion, which makes this a worse match than direct per-class overloads, and
2. has a templated constructor that picks up the actual argument type.

Johannes' original ingenious in-comment idea assumed a fixed function result type and exactly one argument. Generalizing that short idea description to arbitrary result type was not entirely trivial for me because that result type can depend on the actual argument, and one tends to first of all try to automate things like that. Likewise, generalizing to arbitrary number of arguments, with the first one acting as a `this` argument, was not 100% trivial for me. Johannes would no doubt have no problems doing this, and probably in a more neat way than I could do it. Anyway, my code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <utility>


//-------------------------------------- General machinery:

template< class Impl_func, class Result, class... Args >
class Invoker_of_
{
private:
    std::function< auto(Args...) -> Result > f_;

public:
    auto operator()( Args... args ) const -> Result { return f_( args... ); }

    template< class Type >
    Invoker_of_( Type& o )
        : f_(
            [&]( Args... args )
                -> Result
            { return Impl_func{}.operator()( o, args... ); }
            )
    {}
};


//-------------------------------------- General template 1 (foo):

struct Foo_impl
{
    template< class Type >
    auto operator()( Type& o )
        -> int
    { return o.foomethod(); }
};

auto foo( Invoker_of_<Foo_impl, int> const invoker )
    -> int
{ return invoker(); }


//-------------------------------------- General template 2 (bar):

struct Bar_impl
{
    template< class Type >
    auto operator()( Type& o, int const arg1 )
        -> int
    { return o.barmethod( arg1 ); }
};

auto bar( Invoker_of_<Bar_impl, int, int> const invoker, int const arg1 )
    -> int
{ return invoker( arg1 ); }


//--------------------------------------- Usage examples:

struct Base {};
auto foo( Base const& ) -> int { return 101;}
auto bar( Base const&, int x ) -> int { return x + 2; }

struct Derived: Base {};

struct Other
{
    auto foomethod() -> int { return 201; }
    auto barmethod( int const x ) -> int { return x + 2; }
};


//--------------------------------------- Test driver:

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
auto main() -> int
{
    Derived d;
    int const r1 = foo( d );            // OK, invokes non-template overload.
    int const r2 = bar( d, 100 );       // OK, invokes non-template overload.
    cout << r1 << " " << r2 << endl;

    Other o;
    int const r3 = foo( o );            // OK, invokes the general template.
    int const r4 = bar( o, 200 );       // OK, invokes the general template.
    cout << r3 << " " << r4 << endl;
}
```

I have not attempted to support rvalue reference arguments.

Output:

```
101 102
201 202
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid using `std::function`? That'll add a lot of [hidden] overhead here...

Comment: @Barry: I'm not sure it adds overhead at all, not to say "a lot". `std::function` is a very lean beast. But it's possible that there will be overhead, and originally I wrote code that just stored a pointer to the argument, before I realized that that (or at least the way I did it) wouldn't work. The problem is reducing the number arguments, like `std::bind`. Not sure how to do that without replicating much of `std:.function` internals?

Comment: I now suddenly thought it would be easy, then looked at the code, and realized that it would need something like boost::any to store the object pointer, and some type erasure, so that's back to std::function functionality again. Hm.

Comment: But it can be specialized for the case of a single argument, then for that case storing the result in the invoker object as in Johannes' original comment. It's not sure to be more efficient though. Because it almost guarantees a copying (or at least moving) of the result, while the above stands a better chance of RVO, I think.

Comment: I guess we're actually just storing a reference to the passed in object, so that's guaranteed to not use dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 0):

A variation [Johannes Schaub's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36223766/make-fooderived-object-call-foobase-const-instead-of-template-function#comment60079494_36223766), which appears to yield the most clean usage, written up as code for the example at the start:

```
//-------------------------------------- Machinery:

template< class Type >
auto foo_impl( Type& o ) -> int { return o.method(); }

struct Invoker_of_foo_impl
{
    int result;

    template< class Type >
    Invoker_of_foo_impl( Type& o ): result( foo_impl( o ) ) {}
};

auto foo( Invoker_of_foo_impl const invoker ) -> int { return invoker.result; }

//--------------------------------------- Usage:

struct Base {};
auto foo( Base const& ) -> int { return 6*7;}

struct Derived: Base {};

struct Other { auto method() -> int { return 0b101010; } };

auto main() -> int
{
    Derived d;
    foo( d );       // OK, invokes non-template.

    Other o;
    foo( o );       // OK, invokes template
}
```

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf There is a meta post about this Q&A here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319747 . I feel like there are 2 things under the discussion right now: 1) Is this a fully standalone answer? 2) If it is a standalone answer should it be edited into the question or posted as an answer. This Q&A seems to be interesting and of good quality. So I think we all don't want to fill it with an unrelated discussion here?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Barry is just following community recommendations; you should not add your answer to your question, you should post it as an answer. Barry made this a community wiki to ensure the answer is not lost, it certain does not belong in your answer post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The point of a lock down is to *prevent* history changes *while* a dispute is ongoing. Not the opposite on both counts. For the record, any answer of mine would be posted as an answer, and I have certainly not presented this as my answer or as an answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got the problem, but can't you use simply SFINAE and the `is_base_of` trait?
Using them, catch all functions are automatically excluded when the function resolution takes place for a class that is derived from `Base` and the best match is the non-template one.
Moreover, such a solution looks to me as far simpler than all the other... That's why I'm pretty sure that I didn't get the problem!! :-)

Anyway, it follows a working example:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<iostream>

struct Base {};
auto foo( Base const& ) -> int {return 101;}
auto bar( Base const&, int x ) -> int {return x + 2; }

template<class T, typename = typename std::enable_if<not std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value>::type>
auto foo(T & t) -> int {
    return t.foomethod();
}

template<class T, typename = typename std::enable_if<not std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value>::type>
auto bar(T & t, int i) -> int {
    return t.barmethod(i);
}

struct Derived: Base {};

struct Other
{
    auto foomethod() -> int { return 201; }
    auto barmethod( int const x ) -> int { return x + 2; }
};

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
auto main() -> int
{
    Derived d;
    int const r1 = foo( d );            // Invokes the Base arg overload.
    int const r2 = bar( d, 100 );       // Invokes the Base arg overload.
    cout << r1 << " " << r2 << endl;

    Other o;
    int const r3 = foo( o );            // Invokes the general implementation.
    int const r4 = bar( o, 200 );       // Invokes the general implementation.
    cout << r3 << " " << r4 << endl;
}
```

Let me know if I've misunderstood the problem, in that case I'm dropping the answer.

Comment: Thanks! But this limits the general implementation to a pre-determined class or set of classes. A more general SFINAE-based solution was [suggested by Columbo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36223904/464581), but although that allowed arbitrary classes it was IMO not *perfect*. :) When simple client code is main criterion. It was however possibly more efficient than involving a `std::function` instance.

Comment: It actually limits to a subtree of a hierarchy (`is_base_of`). From the question it seems that you want to treat differently all and only those classes that are derived from `Base` indeed. What's exactly the problem? I'd like to think once more on that, if you agree, but I need more details. Thank you.

Comment: Note that this one still works with no changes as long as you continue to extend the hierarchy started from `Base`, so it is *limited to a virtually infinite* (well, if it would make sense) set of classes.