# Make `foo(derived_object, x)` call `foo(Base const&, X)` instead of template function?

Tags: c++, overload-resolution

<sub>Note: This is a **[question-with-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)** in order to document a technique that others might find useful, and in order to perhaps become aware of others’ even better solutions. Do feel free to add critique or questions as comments. Also do feel free to add additional answers. :)</sub>

---

<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36223766/make-fooderived-object-call-foobase-const-instead-of-template-function?noredirect=1#36225486)</sup>**Problem:** how to define “catch all” generic implementations of functions `foo` and `bar` (and other such functions), preferably via a general mechanism, so that e.g. the following code works:

```
struct Base {};
auto foo( Base const& ) -> int { return 101;}
auto bar( Base const&, int x ) -> int { return x + 2; }

struct Derived: Base {};

struct Other
{
    auto foomethod() -> int { return 201; }
    auto barmethod( int const x ) -> int { return x + 2; }
};

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
auto main() -> int
{
    Derived d;
    int const r1 = foo( d );            // Invokes the Base arg overload.
    int const r2 = bar( d, 100 );       // Invokes the Base arg overload.
    cout << r1 << " " << r2 << endl;

    Other o;
    int const r3 = foo( o );            // Invokes the general implementation.
    int const r4 = bar( o, 200 );       // Invokes the general implementation.
    cout << r3 << " " << r4 << endl;
}
```

This is about providing `foo`, `bar` and similar functions by a library. A solution should work for arbitrary user defined classes that the user provides overloads for.

---

<sup><sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36223766/make-fooderived-object-call-foobase-const-instead-of-template-function?noredirect=1#36225486)</sup>This question+answer is an answer to an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36223766/make-fooderived-object-call-foobase-const-instead-of-template-function?noredirect=1#36225486) that has been indefinitely locked down by a moderator, i.e. it's already a duplicate except that no completely satisfactory answer was posted before the lock-down. If the answer below could have been posted there I would have accepted it as solution unless better answers were provided, since it does answer the question. This is not the alleged answer discussed over [at Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319747/editing-potential-answers-into-questions), which e.g. could not handle an argument like `x` in `bar` here, but it's based on that [basic idea put forth by Johannes Schaub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36223766/make-fooderived-object-call-foobase-const-instead-of-template-function?noredirect=1#comment60079494_36223766).</sup>